# Cordova Build Error After Removing And Add The Same Plugin

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova

I am getting build error while I am removing the plugin through Cordova CLI and again add the same plugin. Anybody can help me why I am getting error?

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi myself found the issue. While I am adding plugin to cordova iOS project, required frameworks also getting added to the XCode Project (Frameworks mentioned in plugin.xml). And while I am removing the plugin, the framework already added still remains in the XCode project navigator window. When again I am adding the plugin, cordova not adding the framework to this project hence getting the build error.

**Solution**

- Run Cordova remove plugin through CLI
- Manually remove the unused framework reference from the xcode project.
- Add the plugin through Cordova CLI

I think this  is either a Cordova or XCode  bug. This error is inconsistent and its is happening sometimes. I got this error while developing & testing custom Cordova plugin.

Comment: cordova bug I presume, related to cli. Similar things happen to me constantly.